# Android OpenGL error: "remaining() < needed" and Android 4.4

Tags: android, opengl-es, runtime-error

I am getting an error I do not understand when I try and launch my app on a phone running Android 4.4 (It's a Moto G if this helps):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: remaining() < needed

Exception thrown in Thread[GLThread 85832,5,main] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: remaining < needed
at android.opengl.GLES20.glGetInteger v(Native Method)
at com.jme3.renderer.android.OGLESShaderRenderer.intialize(OGLESShaderRenderer.java:311)
at com.jme3.system.android.OGLESContext.initInThread(OGLESContext.java:215)
at com.jme3.system.android.OGLESContext.onSurfaceCreated(OGLESContext.java:187)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLTread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

When I run the exact same code on an Xperia U running Android 4.0 it runs fine. What is going on here, and what steps can I take to make sure my code runs on a variety of devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One variant of the `glGetIntegerv()` Java bindings takes an `IntBuffer` argument to hold multiple return values.  If your request requires more space than the buffer holds, you will get this error.

Older versions of jMonkeyEngine did a request for `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS` with a fixed-size buffer.  The call failed on devices that supported too many formats.  (You're supposed to query `GL_NUM_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS`, and use that value to size your buffer.)  On older versions of Android this actually caused heap corruption, because the Java-language bindings did the comparison wrong and allowed the data to write past the end of the `IntBuffer` ([fixed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/42137d2e72cebb41f70c4a306877587fd0ea8c20)).

You can see the fix to jMonkeyEngine [applied here](https://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/detail?r=10137).  Judging by the line number in the exception, you're using a version of jMonkeyEngine that pre-dates the fix.

Comment: I updated to the newest version of the jMonkey SDK and it fixed it. Thank you very much.