# troubleshooting to get a basicgame running on android using jmonkeyengine

Tags: java, android, jmonkeyengine

i’m trying to get my basic game running in android using jmonkey i've followed a few tutorials and did everything that jmonkey documentation told me to.

so here’s the error i’m getting:

```
E/AndroidHarness(13363): Exception thrown in Thread[GLThread 20934,5,main]
E/AndroidHarness(13363): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: remaining() < needed
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at android.opengl.GLES20.glGetIntegerv(Native Method)
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at com.jme3.renderer.android.OGLESShaderRenderer.initialize(OGLESShaderRenderer.java:311)
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at com.jme3.system.android.OGLESContext.initInThread(OGLESContext.java:215)
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at com.jme3.system.android.OGLESContext.onSurfaceCreated(OGLESContext.java:187)
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
E/AndroidHarness(13363):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

any idea what i’m doing wrong? or forgot. or how to solve this.

anyway thanks for your time, Niels

Comment: We'll need to see the code that created this exception (or preferably a [cut down version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to be able to answer this

Comment: i didn't change anything the basic-game just auto generates it self. but if i click the links i'm getting somewhere i'm not even allowed to make changes. do i still need to paste that code?

Comment: Might as well, but you are right, the issue is unlikely to be there. Do PC JMonkey programs work correctly for you?

Comment: Incidently; how old is your version of JMonkey. I note this issue here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941756/android-opengl-error-remaining-needed-and-android-4-4

Comment: Yes my pc programs work right. I've got JMonkeyEngine SDK 3.0RC2 installed. I will try to update my jmonkey now.

Answer (score 0):

if you got this error or something like it and your game hasn't been started before, you should update your jmonkey becouse that was the problem

Richard Tingle thank you!

,Niels

Comment: Glad its sorted, I had a feeling this would be the issue. I'm going to vote to close this question as a duplicate of [Android OpenGL error: “remaining() < needed” and Android 4.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941756/android-opengl-error-remaining-needed-and-android-4-4) now to more tightly couple the two questions